# Cannot use SimpleAdapter on a ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, simpleadapter

I'm developing a ListView in an Android Fragment. The class extends ListFragment.

I tried with this example:
http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

but the problem is that constructor SimpleAdapter is not defined if the class extends ListFragment, changing it to ListActivity would make SimpleAdapter work, but then application won't.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View tmp_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clients_list, container, false);
    ListView list = (ListView) tmp_view.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("train", "101");
    map.put("from", "6:30 AM");
    map.put("to", "7:40 AM");
    mylist.add(map);
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("train", "103(x)");
    map.put("from", "6:35 AM");
    map.put("to", "7:45 AM");
    mylist.add(map);
    // ...
    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.clients_list_item,
                new String[] {"train", "from", "to"}, new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.TO_CELL});
    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
    ListFragment.setListAdapter(mSchedule);


    return tmp_view;
}
```

So I will have no problem if this was an Activity, but it's a Fragment :S Any solution?

Comment: you have a set one adapter already, try removing ListFragment.setListAdapter(mSchedule); this line.

Comment: I Know, was just trying things, btw the problem is in the SimpleAdapter line. Constructor is not defined. I want to solve this problem, setting the list adapter is fine. Thank you btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found solution by using a custom adapter:
http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/

Comment: Can you share your fixed code? Because I seem to have a similar problem but I cannot find a solution

Answer (score 5):

ListFragment is not a subclass of Context, which the constructor needs. Try replacing

```
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, ...
```

with

```
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mylist, ...
```